# Python best practice import submodule in submodule

Tags: python, python-module

I'm currently reading about Python's submodule in submodule imports and somehow I can't find a proper answer. Here is an example:

```
root/
     main.py
     moduleA/
             __init__.py
             log.py
     moduleB/
             __init__.py
             worker.py
```

I'd like to import `log` in `worker` by using `import moduleA.log`. And I'd like to import `worker` in `main` and use it there.

So far I've found the following solutions:

- Append `sys.path` with `../` (`sys.path.append('../')`)
- I read something about using `pip -e` to install my module into the environment.
- Avoiding scripts which import from submodules.

I've read that the `sys.path` hack is considered the best practice. But somehow it feels wrong.

So I'd like to know what is considered best practice by you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use relative imports to solve this issue:

In `main.py` write

```
from .moduleB import worker
```

In `worker.py`:

```
from ..moduleA import log
```

One dot takes the current directory as beginning of the path, so `.moduleB` digs into the folder `moduleB` below the current dir.
Two dots moves one dir upwards, so `..moduleA` in goes up to the `root` directory and then down to `moduleA`. Each additional dot is one directory up.
F.i. `from . import ab` would import `ab.py` from the same directory.
Packaging/installing a module is not necessary to do relative imports. But you have to import with `from ..moduleA import log`. Importing with `import ..moduleA.log` won't work with relative imports.

Answer (score 0):

I'll typically use a `modulename.py` file that contains all the imports, which I can refer to later:

With your structure:

```
root/
     __init__.py
     root.py
     modulea/
         __init__.py
         a.py
      moduleb/
         __init__.py
         b.py
```

The `root.py` would be:

```
from modulea.a import sleep, eat, breath
from moduleb.b import read, write, watch
```

such that I can later do

```
from package.root import sleep, read, watch
```

However, this requires having your package installed, which may not always be practical.

Answer (score -1):

I personally prefer to change my current working directory and import just in case i ever run into this issue.

```
root/
     __init__.py
     root.py
     modulea/
             __init__.py
             a.py
     moduleb/
             __init__.py
             b.py
```

Given a setup like this,

```
a.py
def a():
    print("i am a")
```

And in b, just change current directory to root using either absolute or relative path via `os.chdir`

```
b.py

def b():
    print("i am b")

import os
os.chdir('..')
from modulea.a import a
a()
```

Running b.py prints `i am a`

The other options are out there, sys.path or PYTHONPATH modifications. [Refer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/714063/importing-modules-from-parent-folder/50194143#50194143)

I do however also recommend avoiding such scenarios best you can as far as possible.